# Сочинительная связь между разноимёнными членами предложения

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, союзы, члены-предложения

*Всегда делай чуть больше и лучше, чем от тебя ожидается.*

"Иногда сочинительная связь может соединять и разноимённые члены предложения, например: *Неизвестно, кто и как разнес по тайге весть о гибели старого сокжоя* (Федосеев). Союзные слова в придаточном предложении являются разными членами предложения (подлежащее кто и обстоятельство образа действия как, но связаны они сочинительным союзом и)" (http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/723-27_odnorodnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html).

Допустимо ли в моём случае поставить сочинительный союз "и" между неоднородными членами, в данном случае дополнением и обстоятельством?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Всегда делай чуть больше и лучше, чем от тебя ожидается.**

Сравнить: **Выполняй работу (как?) лучше и в большем объеме, чем от тебя ожидается.**

Поэтому нет здесь разноименных членов предложения, больше и лучше ― это однородные обстоятельства.